# What is the topology here with three elements in sets?

Tags: general-topology

What is $\tau$ for my paint drawn picture below?

I can't decide between these two interpretations:
$$1)\, \tau = \{a,b,c,\{b\},\{a,b,\{b\}\},\{b,c,\{b\}\}$$
and the simpler
$$2)\,\tau=\{\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{b\}\}$$

Perhaps both are incorrect even.

---

[image]

---

Don't know what to title it as, since the title would normally include the topology :P

Comment: Remember that $\tau$ is supposed to be a collection of *subsets* of $\{a,b,c\}$, hence the elements $a,b,c$ can't be sets in $\tau$, same of things like $\{a,b,\{b\}\}$ which is not a subset of $\{a,b,c\}$.

Comment: @James Ahhh yes true, thank you, I had forgotten. Always hard to realise you need to recap things months later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are incorrect. The first one because topology is a collection of subsets, and your suggested collection is not. The second one is not a topology because $\emptyset$ and $\{a,b,c\}$ are missing from it. That being said, once you include those two you get the correct set. Which is 
\begin{align*}
\tau=\{\emptyset,\{a,b\},\{b\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, and if I take the complement of $\{b\}$ I get $\tau$ above without $\{b\}$ in it?

Comment: @Topology: The complement of $\{b\}$ is $\{a,c\}$, which is neither an element of $\tau$, nor $\tau$ without $\{b\}$ in it.